# Why are my tab contents not refreshing?

Tags: jquery, html, json, youtube, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page with several tabs on it. When the user enters a value in a text input and then mashes a button, I want to replace the contents on a particular tab. I have this code (some of the details are elided to show just the pertinent parts/explain what I'm doing).

It works great the first time - the tab loads just fine; *subsequent* clicks of the button (after changing the text input value) has no effect, though. Why not? What must I do to force the tab to "refresh"? Something equivalent, perhaps, to a "Application.ProcessMessages()" in a desktop environment?

Here's the pertinent html:

```
<input type="text" name="inputText" id="inputText" placeholder="Enter something" autofocus style="display: inline-block;" />
<input type="button" name="inputButton" id="inputButton" value="Find" style="display: inline-block;" />
```

...and  jQuery:

```
<script>
    $.support.cors = true; 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#duckbilledPlatypusTabs").tabs({
        });

        $("#inputButton").click(function (e) {
                var searchTerm = "";
                if ($("#inputText").val() !== "") {
                    searchTerm = $("#inputText").val();
                } else {
                    searchTerm = "jQuery";
                }
                //alert(searchTerm);
                $("duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube").html("");

                var urlYouTube = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=" + searchTerm + "&max-results=5&orderby=published&alt=json";

                $.getJSON(urlYouTube, function (data) {
                    // Loop through each feed entry
                    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                        // Get the URL for the video
                        var url = item.link[0].href;
                        // Get the title of the video
                        var title = item.title.$t;
                        // Get the first 10 characters of date video was published or: YYYY-MM-DD
                        var datepublished = item.published.$t.substring(0, 10);
                        // Get the author name
                        var author = item.author[0].name.$t;
                        // Get the thumbnail image for the video
                        var thumbnailURL = item.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
                        // Construct the display for the video
                        var text =
                            "<br><a href='" + url + "'>" + title + "</a><br>" +
                                "Published: " + datepublished + " by " + author + "<br><br>" +
                                "<img src='" + thumbnailURL + "'><br>";
                        // Append the text string to the div for display
                        $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube").append(text);
                    });
                });
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `#` in `$("duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube").html("");`. Actually, your code fails to clear the "YouTube" tab, so all new videos are appended at the end of the container.
Correcting that to `$("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-YouTube").html("");` should solve your problem.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/XVsJA/)**.
(Basically, all I did was take your code and add this missing `#`.)